# Implementing interface based on the chosen interface

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, interface, solid-principles

So if I have an interface `iConnection`

```
interface iConnection
{
}
```

Which is implemented by:

```
class OutlookConnection implements iConnection
{
}
```

And

```
class GoogleConnection implements iConnection
{
}
```

And another interface `iComparison`

```
interface iComparison
{
}
```

Which is implemented by:

```
class OutlookComparison implements iComparison
{
  private $connection;
  public function __construct($user, iConnection $iConnection) {
   $this->connection = $iConnection;
  }
}
```

And

```
class GoogleComparison implements iComparison
{
  private $connection;
  public function __construct($user, iConnection $iConnection) {
   $this->connection = $iConnection;
  }
}
```

In the main program I want to be able to switch between GoogleComparison and OutlookComparison based on the iConnection type without using an if or switch statement:

```
public function __construct(iConnection $connection)
{
    $this->connect = $connection;
    if($this->connection instanceof GoogleConnection){
      $this->comparison = new GoogleComparison();
    }
    elseif($this->connection instanceof OutlookConnection){
      $this->comparison = new OutlookComparison();
    }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve within this constructor without switch or if statements?

Comment: Can't you make connection instance responsible for providing comparison? How about `$connection->getComparison()`?

Comment: Ah yess that would work thanks. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an architectural issue. I suggest passing responsibility for providing `comparison` to the `connection`. **One of the possible solutions could look like this below**.

First - interface gets getter stub:

```
interface iConnection
{
    public function getComparison();
}
```

Then - all the different connections implement it as you want, for example:

```
class OutlookConnection implements iConnection
{
    public function getComparison()
    {
        return new OutlookComparison();
    }
}
```

And finally, your construction similar to:

```
public function __construct(iConnection $connection)
{
    $this->connect = $connection;
    $this->comparison = $connection->getComparison();
}
```

From now on, you can either operate on comparison property or simply `$this->connect->getComparison()->fooBarBaz()`. All depends on your needs.